# Making Multi-row work in pandas dataframe.to_latex()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, latex

I have the following dataframe:

```
      dataset Baseline       Version2      
               F-1   F-2      F-1   F-2
0       G    0.971 0.967    0.971 0.967
1       H    0.780 0.762    0.800 0.777
2       S    0.401 0.320    0.453 0.365
3       T    0.881 0.825    0.989 0.985
```

My goal is to export this to LaTeX, which I do by pandas.DataFrame.to_latex():

```
latex = df.to_latex(
        index=False,
        escape=False,
        sparsify=True,
        multirow=True,
        multicolumn=True,
        multicolumn_format='c',
        position='H'
    )
```

obtaining the following code in LaTeX:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lrrrr}
\toprule
dataset & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Baseline} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Version2} \\
        &      F-1 &   F-2 &      F-1 &   F-2 \\
\midrule
      G &    0.971 & 0.967 &    0.971 & 0.967 \\
      H &    0.780 & 0.762 &    0.800 & 0.777 \\
      S &    0.401 & 0.320 &    0.453 & 0.365 \\
      T &    0.881 & 0.825 &    0.989 & 0.985 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

which is rendered like this:
[image]
My issue is: I'd expect a multirow to appear in the "dataset", covering the 2 lines with "dataset" and "", like this:
[image]
I have `multirow=True` in the options, but I can't make this work. Any idea on how can I fix this?

Comment: pandas will not add a multirow to a column header. There is no combination of options to do this. Whilst it may visually represent a single item that column header is a tuple of two items `("dataset", "")`

Answer (score 1):

I prefer something slightly different, namely **do not mix visually indexes and columns**. Here the index is "dataset" and columns are hierarchical under "Benchmark" and "Version2" as roots.
[image]

To achieve this, start with the following data file

```
        dataset Baseline       Version2      
               F-1   F-2      F-1   F-2
0       G    0.971 0.967    0.971 0.967
1       H    0.780 0.762    0.800 0.777
2       S    0.401 0.320    0.453 0.365
3       T    0.881 0.825    0.989 0.985
```

Then generate the table

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt',header=None,sep=r'\s+',skiprows=2, index_col=0)
df.set_index(1,inplace=True)
df.index.name='Dataset'
columns = [
    ('Baseline','F-1'),
    ('Baseline','F-2'),
    ('Version2','F-1'),
    ('Version2','F-2')
]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns)
df.head()
```

and the latex code

```
latex = df.to_latex(
        index=True,
        escape=False,
        sparsify=True,
        multirow=True,
        multicolumn=True,
        multicolumn_format='c',
        position='p',
        bold_rows=True
    )
```